# How to play/start vimeo video after clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some code, that works good with youtube videos, but I need the same effect with vimeo videos, wondering how to do this, any suggestions? Need replace youtube discription by vimeo but I don't know how to do this.
P.S Sorry for my English...

```
<style type="text/css">
#head {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:520px;
    height:380px;
}

.inactive-state {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url();
}
.hover-state {
    background-image: url();
}
</style>
        <section id="head">
    <div id="container" class="click-to-play-video inactive-state">
        <div id="player" class="home-player"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#container").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover-state');
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover-state');
    });

    $("#container.click-to-play-video").click(function () {
        $('#head').css({ "background-color": "transparent" });

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width: '520',
            height: '300',
            videoId: 'qlEUrEVqDbo',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    });

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        //event.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.destroy();
            $('#head').css({ "background-color": "transparent" });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think this may also be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812091/vimeo-player-api-play-video-with-javascript

Answer (score -2):

In it's most simple form, you'll want something like this. Just remove the image and append the iframe, with autoplay on.

```
$('.vimeo-img').click(function (event) {

  var $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.parent();

  $this.remove();

  $parent().append('<iframe src="..." autoplay="true"></iframe>');
})
```

Comment: elzi Thanks, I found even shorter way to do this!

Comment: `$(this).replace('<iframe>')` ? :P