# How can I use the new (2016) Vimeo javascript API to start a video?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Vimeo has a [new (2016) javascript API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/blob/master/README.md). I'm looking for a **basic example** of it in use to **start and stop a video by javascript when clicking something on the page**.

I found those two articles covering the topics, but both are about the old frogaloop api:

- [Vimeo player api - play video with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812091/vimeo-player-api-play-video-with-javascript)
- https://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/

Comment: that page you linked has examples and the api docs.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes but it doesn't have the example that is asked for in the question ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a Vimeo video via the new javascript API you simply have to include the API in your page and then execute the `play` method. See example below:

```html
<!-- Load the video iframe. Be sure to not forget to enable the api (api=1) -->
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/87982573?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!-- When clicking this text the video will start -->
<p id='start'>click to start</p>

<!-- Including jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Including Vimeo player javascript API -->
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
  
<script>
  var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
  // Execute the `play` method of the API when something with id start is clicked
  $('#start').click( function() {
    player.play();
  });
</script>
```

And be sure to have a look at [Vimeos example page for the new player API](https://player.vimeo.com/api/demo).